# Dynamic generate function with ordered default kwargs in python

Tags: python, types, metaprogramming

I want to generate a class with a customized `__init__`function.

For example:

```
l = [('a', 1), ('b', 'foo'), ('c', None)]
```

generates:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b='foo', c=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I know this can be done with something like:

```
def __init___(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

But the previous one can do 2 more things:

1. the `__init__` should only accept `a`, `b`, `c`
2. I can call it with `A(2, 'bar')` and `a`, `b`, `c` were assigned with correct order.

So I really want to generate a function with ordered default kwargs.

It seems the function can be built with types.FunctionType with co_varnames and defaults, but the documents and exampels are very hard to find.

What's the best way to do this?

---

Update:

I got this implementation myself after some trying

```
import types


def init_generator(spec):
    """Generate `__init__` function based on spec
    """
    varnames, defaults = zip(*spec)
    varnames = ('self', ) + varnames

    def init(self):
        kwargs = locals()
        kwargs.pop('self')
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    code = init.__code__
    new_code = types.CodeType(len(spec) + 1,
                              0,
                              len(spec) + 2,
                              code.co_stacksize,
                              code.co_flags,
                              code.co_code,
                              code.co_consts,
                              code.co_names,
                              varnames,
                              code.co_filename,
                              "__init__",
                              code.co_firstlineno,
                              code.co_lnotab,
                              code.co_freevars,
                              code.co_cellvars)
    return types.FunctionType(new_code,
                              {"__builtins__": __builtins__},
                              argdefs=defaults)


class A(object):
    pass


spec = [('a', 1), ('b', 'foo'), ('c', None)]
A.__init__ = init_generator(spec)
a = A(2, c='wow!')
# {'a': 2, 'b': 'foo', 'c': 'wow!'}
print(a.__dict__)

import inspect
# ArgSpec(args=['self', 'a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(1, 'foo', None))
print(inspect.getargspec(A.__init__))
```

The only thing bothers me now is the `locals()` in the `init()`, which may be unsafe?

Can it be refined to something better?

Comment: I'd be tempted to use eval() for this.

Comment: The complication with using eval for this, beyond validating the argument names, is that you can't just string-format the default values into place. `<object object at 0xwherever>` isn't valid code for a default argument. You'd have to generate variables to hold the default values. It could get a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def generate(name, ordered_args):

        cls = type(name, (object,), {})

        def init(self, *args, **kwargs):

           _dict = dict(ordered_args)

            if len(args) > len(_dict):
                raise TypeError('Too many args')

            _args = dict(zip([a[0] for a in ordered_args], args))

            for arg in _args:
                if arg in kwargs:
                    raise TypeError('Multiple keyowrd arg')

            _args.update(kwargs)

            for arg in _args:
                if arg not in _dict:
                    raise TypeError('Unexpected keyword arg')

            _dict.update(_args)            

            for arg, val in _dict.items():
                setattr(self, arg, val)

        setattr(cls, '__init__', init)

        return cls



    A = generate('A', [('a',1), ('b', None)])
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
In [1]: from functools import partial

In [2]: basetwo = partial(int, base=2)

In [3]: basetwo("10010")
Out[3]: 18

In [4]: basetwo("0x10", base=16)
Out[4]: 16
```

Comment: This isn't actually applicable to the OP's situation.